# Are there any websites to check if my luggage will be accepted at airports?

Tags: luggage, online-resources, airport-security, hand-luggage

I'm completely new to travelling and I will fly to Ireland in two weeks from school.

I looked up luggage rules on the internet but I don't completely understand them, especially the rules for hand luggage.

Is there a website where I can type in a list of all my stuff for hand luggage and hold bagagge and check if it fits with the safety rules at airports?

Are there any websites that inform me about the security process in airports? I only know that the hand luggage is scanned. I don't know where I should store my notebook for example.

I'm especially interested in where to put:

- electronic devices
- liquids

I already know that there are very strict rules for liquids in hand luggage but what about my suitcase? Electronic devices should be in hand luggage but what about a big laptop?

Comment: Are you looking for rules in terms of what is accepted or not for safety reasons, or for rules in terms of maximum number, size and weight? The latter at least will depend on what airline you are flying (as well as class of travel, frequent flyer status, etc. but I doubt those would be relevant for you). You may also want to include the two airports or at least countries involved.

Comment: @jcaron I kind of want to know the rules of what is accpeted. I've already read some of the rules but don't quite understand them so I'm just looking for a website where I can type in what I actually have in my suitcase and it tells me if it is legal or not.

Comment: @Serafina Reisinger I would always carry valuable items like a notebook, iPad etc in my hand luggage. When you pass through security laptops, mobiles etc have to be removed from your luggage case and placed in the tray for scanning, along with all liquids. The latter need to be in a see through bag (1 per passenger), which are typically available at the airport before you get to security. The information provided by airline carriers is usually pretty comprehensive

Comment: @Traveller Yeah, I've already read that. But I don't quite understand why anyone should have liquids in hand luggage. In my suitcase liquids are allowed, no matter in which quantity?

Comment: @Serafina Reisinger It’s a good idea to have a small supply of toiletries in your hand luggage in case your hold luggage goes astray. For the same reason I always make sure I have what I consider to be my essentials (in my case hair straighteners/dryer, toiletries & contact lenses) in my hand luggage, along with enough clothes to get me through a couple of days in case of need. I once spent a weekend in Rome without my hold case, it’s not as easy as you’d imagine to buy replacements (sizes differ, for example).

Comment: I don't imagine there is such a site because the rules are not complicated enough to justify programming it.

Comment: Another reason people carry liquids in their carry-on is that they are not checking in a bag.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to note

1. It can be confusing: Every airline has their own set of rules and it can even vary with aircraft type and type of ticket
2. I don't think there is a single website that has all regulations in one spot. Check with the airlines you are trying to fly with. For example: here is what United has https://www.united.com/CMS/en-US/travel/Pages/BaggageCarry-On.aspx
3. It's not quite as complicated as they make it out to be. It typically works as follows
4. For **checked bags** (cargo hold) you have a baggage allowance which depends on your ticket. It spells out the number of suitcases and the maximum weight. There is also a size restriction but unless you have a really unusual piece of luggage, that's not a problem. If you exceed the weight or number, you need to pay extra. Typical example would be "1 suitcase of up to 23 kg".
5. **On the plane:** Most airlines allow you to bring one carry-on bag plus a personal item (back pack or purse) on the plane.
6. **Carry on** is restricted by size or weight (or both). A standard roller board (22 cm x 35 cm x 56 cm), will fit pretty much any regular aircraft. Weight limits do depend on the airline. Lufthansa, for example, limits to 8 kg https://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/Carry-on-baggage. United does not restrict weight.
7. If it's a very small aircraft that doesn't fit a normal carry, they "gate check" the bag: You give it to them when you board and you get it back right at the gate when you exit (not on the regular baggage claim).
8. **Personal Item**: That's typically a back pack or a purse. Usually, they are not picky about the size if it first under the seat in front of you. That's different if you have a "basic economy" or highly restricted ticket. In general, the cost savings aren't worth the bother, so I would avoid these
9. **What goes where**: If you check a bag, put all the liquids in there. If you don't, you have to make sure that you that all liquids are less than 100ml and fit into a quart (1 liter) sized bag. Keep laptops, notepads, phones with you in carry on. In fact, laptop batteries are not allowed in the cargo hold.
10. **At security**: Every airport has somewhat different rules, but typically you need to take out liquids (up to 100 ml each), laptops & tablets. Empty all your pockets. Take off coat, shoes and belt. All that stuff goes through an X-ray machine while you go through a metal scanner or body scanner. Once you are through, you can collect your stuff and repack everything. It's easy enough: just watch what everybody else is doing.

Comment: Regarding #9, there's an extra complication with Lithium batteries (i.e. most batteries these days). I've had mine confiscated from check-in luggage (with an appropriate notice), and honestly had no idea they were restricted. They're supposed to go in a carry-on, but there are restrictions on quantity/capacity that vary by country and airline.